# Routing for .json and .xml

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm new to MVC3 coming from CakePHP, and have been quite impressed. But I've run into some growing pains. I'm working on developing a Flex application with an ASP.NET backend, so I would like to be able to use my HTML views for testing and xml or json for data transfer to the Flex Frontend.

In CakePHP we use the RequestHandler class to handle routing extensions.

- MyController/Details/14 -> returns html view
- MyController/Details/14.json -> returns json view
- MyController/Details/14.xml -> xml view

and in the Controller Class I would do something like this phpish pseudo-code:

```
Details(id)
{
    $data = $this->MyController->findById(id);

    if($this->requestType == "json")
    {
        respondAs("json");
    }
    else if($this->requestType == "xml")
    {
        respondAs("xml");
    }
    else
    {
        //does default - html view
    }

    $this->setViewVariable("data", $data);
}
```

Would anyone be able to give me some tips to help accomplish something similar with MVC3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [following blog post](http://omaralzabir.com/create_rest_api_using_asp_net_mvc_that_speaks_both_json_and_plain_xml/).

Comment: Thanks, I like that way even better with the RESTful urls.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass in a route value along with the id `MyController/Details/14/xml`

You would need to modify your routes to allow for this as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{type}", 
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, type = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Then in your `HomeController` your action would look something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(int id, string type)
{
   if(type == "json")
      return View("JsonView");

   //etc
}
```

You would obviously need to check the value of `type` properly for `null` or what-have-you